# Vue.Js: List rendering

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am doing this little code challenge :

We provided some simple `Vue.js` template code. Your goal is first to set items equal to an array of three objects with the following properties:

> name = Daniel, age = 25 - name = John, age = 24 - name = Jen, age = 31.

Then in the `template`, you should display an unordered list (`UL`) with list items (`LI`) within it. The content of each list item should contain two spans (`SPAN`), one with the `name` and the other with the `age`. The span elements should be separated by a single space.

With my code below nothing happens when I try to run the program. (Not sure if it's because it's in a browser).

Here's my code :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="item in items">
        {{name}} {{age}}
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        items: 
        [
          { name: 'Daniel' },
          { age: '25' },
          { name: 'John' },
          { age: '25' },
          { name: 'Jen' },
          { age: '31' }
        ]
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

**Edit for comment section**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <ul>
      <li v-for="({name,age}) in items">
        <span>{{name}}</span> <span>{{age}}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "App",
    data() {
      return {
        items: 
        [
          {name: 'Daniel', age: '25'},
          {name: 'John', age: '25'},
          {name: 'Jen', age: '31'}

        ]
      };
    }
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create only three objects in `items`, each having `name` and `age`. Then, in the `v-for`, you can deconstruct each item in the array and print the attributes in two space-sperated `span` elements:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      items:  [
        { name: 'Daniel', age: '25' },
        { name: 'John', age: '25' },
        { name: 'Jen', age: '31' }
      ]
    };
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
  
<div id="app">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="({name,age}, index) in items" :key="index">
      <span>{{ name }}</span>{{ ' ' }}<span>{{ age }}</span>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: nice, thanks for reply, everything is working but what if i want a space between my two spans ? so i get Daniel 25 and not Daniel25? Ty !

Comment: @codetime you're welcome. This solution adds a space between the ``name`` and the ``age`` if you run the above snippet

Comment: that's weird when i run your snippet it works but not in my code, i added an edit with my code nownot sure what is causing that, it's the same as you :O

Comment: @codetime I updated the answer with a possible fix